# Address with Suite or other secondary address yields no autocomplete results

Tags: here-api

I'm running into an issue where addresses typed/pasted into the form field are not coming back with any autocomplete results due to their secondary address being included. For example, the following query works fine:

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=...&app_code=...&query=1910%20W%20Fourth%20Plain%20Blvd&country=USA&maxresults=5
```

However, this query (The actual full address) returns no results:

```
http://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?app_id=...&app_code=...&query=1910%20W%20Fourth%20Plain%20Blvd%20Suite%20100%2C%20Vancouver%2C%20WA%2098660&country=USA&maxresults=5
```

Is there a way to allow for secondary address info such as Suite, Apt, etc.?

Comment: The search algorithm within the autocomplete API can return results on match levels: `country, state, county, city, district, street, intersection, houseNumber, postalCode` and `landmark`.You get results back if you replace Suite with # which the API understands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search algorithm within the autocomplete API can return results on match levels: `country, state, county, city, district, street, intersection, houseNumber, postalCode and landmark.`You get results back if you replace Suite with # which the API understands

https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/dev_guide/topics/resource-suggest.html

Comment: So my address would need to be formatted as `1910%20W%20Fourth%20Plain%20Blvd%20%23100` (1910 W Fourth Plain Blvd #100) in order to be found, is that what you mean? Thanks!